# redux: re-render component after async fetch & document creation

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I have a component that upon `componentDidMount` will perform an async API database fetch.

On the same component the user can add an item to the collection. Unfortunately, the component does not automatically re-render, even though the new document was added to the collection. How do I invoke another render with the new document showing as well?

Comment: Could you elaborate more ? simple sample code, will give better overview what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If your collection is an array, when an item was created you should return a new array by using `concat` method instead of `push` or access directly into the array via the index.

See this code:

```
const myReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESSFUL': return action.data

        case 'NEW_ITEM': return [].concat(state, [action.newItem])

    }
}
```

When you return a new array, `redux` will know the state was changed and your component will also update automatically.